# What is the name of this type of attack using transparent encryption?

Tags: cryptography, attacks, backup

I don't know or remember the name for the following attack and I can't find it on the web.

Using transparent encryption (e.g. TDE) to encrypt data (e.g. databases) over a long period of time, so that also backups are encrypted, and then remove the key to make the data (including backups) unavailable.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a name for the technique, but it's a popular technique. I believe a lot of hard drives and SSDs internally use encryption automatically so that they can offer a quick "secure erase" feature that just dumps the keys.

Comment: @AgentME The technique for storage devices is SED.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that sounds like an Advanced Persistent Threat (APT), but specifically, this would count as Ransomware if you try to sell the key back to the victim, Data Destruction if you don't. WannaCry was an example of both, where the malefactors didn't really keep the keys and anyone who paid was doubly screwed.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was looking for. The technique I am looking for is used in APTs and in ransom scenarios, but I'm interested in the name for the technique itself.

Comment: If there's a specific term for this, I look forward to learning it also!